# Spring session with Oracle Coherence

Tags: spring, spring-session

We have a large-scale monolithic application which we are planing to decompose into microservices. The  application runs on WebLogic and we wanted to use oracle-coherence with spring-session. However I could not find a spring-session-coherence project on github.

Is oracle coherence already supported by spring session?

Comment: Is oracle coherence already supported by spring session? Updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Session does not provide first-class support for Oracle Coherence and, to my knowledge, there are no 3rd party extensions that offer such capability ATM.

You can however use Spring Session and its base session management support infrastructure using [`@EnableSpringHttpSession`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/1.2.2.RELEASE/reference/html5/#api-enablespringhttpsession) and on top of that provide your custom `SessionRepository` implementation that can be backed by technology of your choice.

Comment: The Coherence Spring project provides Spring Session support https://github.com/coherence-community/coherence-spring

Answer (score -2):

> Is oracle coherence already supported by spring session?

Short answer is **YES**.

I found this [official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15357_01/coh.360/e15830/integratespring.htm#COHIG167) to integrate Spring with Oracle Coherence.

Comment: It's how coherence cache is injected as a bean - not for spring session

Comment: If it is available as spring bean, then it should work with spring session or whatever sub-framework/library from spring family.

Comment: The provided link does not mention Spring Session - take a look at the [reference documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/1.2.2.RELEASE/reference/html5/) to familiarize yourself with the project and get a feeling what would constitute a first class support for Spring Session.